# Copying Multiple files using SWT filedialog

Tags: java, swt, filedialog

I'm working a transfer file program and my program is working but I'm having a problem because when I select multiple files and put it on a `textbox` the source directory can't read what is on the `textbox`

this is my code

**Opening file/files**

```
btnSearchFile.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.MULTI);
        Collection files = new ArrayList();
        String firstFile = fd.open();
        if (firstFile != null) {
            String[] selectedFiles = fd.getFileNames();
            File file = new File(firstFile);
            for (int ii = 0; ii < selectedFiles.length; ii++ )
            {
                if (file.isFile())
                {
                    displayFiles(new String[] { file.toString()});
                }
                else
                    displayFiles(file.list());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Displaying Files on textbox**

```
public void displayFiles(String[] files) {
    for (int i = 0; files != null && i < files.length; i++) {
        txtSource.append(files[i]);
        txtSource.setEditable(false);
    }
}
```

**Copy Files**

```
public static void copyFile(File src, File dest) throws IOException
{
    InputStream oInStream = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream oOutStream = new FileOutputStream(dest);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] oBytes = new byte[1024];
    int nLength;
    BufferedInputStream oBuffInputStream = new BufferedInputStream( oInStream );
    while ((nLength = oBuffInputStream.read(oBytes)) > 0)
    {
        oOutStream.write(oBytes, 0, nLength);
    }
    oInStream.close();
    oOutStream.close();
}
```

PS: One file is okay but if multiple files are selected and put on the textbox the source directory can't be found

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "the source directory can't read what is on the textbox"?  What is `txtSource` in your code -- is it a `Text` widget or something else?

Comment: sorry for the long late reply, and yes `txtSource` is a `Text` widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be completely helpful, we could really use some more detail (specific exceptions, a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which SWT widgets are used, etc.).

That said, I think you've provided enough to see that there are some issues with your code:

1. For starters, when you have multiple files selected, you're displaying the same file name (the name of the first one) over and over. Perhaps this is intentional, but worth mentioning:

   ```
   String[] selectedFiles = fd.getFileNames();
   File file = new File(firstFile);
   for (int ii = 0; ii < selectedFiles.length; ii++ )
   {
       // You've used a FileDialog, so this should always be true
       if (file.isFile())
       {
           // Will always be the first file
           displayFiles(new String[] { file.toString()});
       }
       else
           displayFiles(file.list());
   }
   ```
2. Based on the context, I'm assuming `txtSource` is a `Text` widget. With that in mind, if we look at your `displayFiles()` method, you have the following:

   ```
   txtSource.append(files[i]);
   ```

   When you call `displayFiles()` repeatedly, you will be tacking on a file name after all the others, effectively building one long `String` which is the combination of all file names. When you go to copy the files listed, splitting that `String` back into valid file paths will be tricky.

   My guess is that when you say:

   > "the source directory can't be found"

   ...you're just grabbing the content of `txtSource`. Something like this:

   ```
   new File(txtSource.getText());
   ```

   > "...One file is okay..."

   That will certainly work if there's only one file name in the `Text` object, but if there are multiple names it will result in a non-existent `File`.

   For example, if you've selected two files:

   - C:\Users\me\FileA
   - C:\Users\me\FileB

   Your `txtSource` would display `C:\Users\me\FileAC:\Users\me\FileB`. And the path `C:\Users\me\FileAC:\Users\me\FileB` most likely does not exist.

   In that case, `new File(txtSource.getText()).exists()` would return `false`, and using that `File` in the constructor for `FileInputStream` (inside `copyFile()`) would result in a `FileNotFoundException`.

---

In short, just make sure that when you make your call to `copyFile()` and create the source `File` object that you're giving the path that you think you are, and not the concatenation of all files selected.

Comment: thank you for posting this @avojak, and I get your point actually all you had listed on the top is all correct. I did what you said but i can't get what do I change on my codes.